# 404 Not Found when displaying a product after reindexing

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, indexing

Before reindexing Magento I can see a product detail but after reindexing, I can't see the product detail. And the weird thing is when I search for some products I can find it, this one works well before and after reindexing

Answer (score 0):

As per you when you search product display and when you go through the menu or listing page it shows 404 pages.

This means Url is not generated properly.

So go to any product page change URL and save it then see if it displaying or not.

If Display then Take mysqldump (database backup) and then search for url_rewrite and then truncate it without checking foreign key.

then install [this](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) using the composer and run this command one by one.

```
php bin/magento regenerate:category:path
php bin/magento regenerate:category:url
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url
```

Might solve your issue
Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But unfortunately, the problem is in my Observer. I used the wrong namespace in it, so the class that I used in that observer can't be detected so it results  404

Comment: Oh okay - At last issue resolve that matter

Comment: Yeah..I need to be careful more